# Jsmin on folder with subfolders

Tags: javascript, compression

I am running jsmin to compress all the javascript files of my ASP.Net web application as a postbuild event in the csproj file like this:

> "JsMin.exe"
>   "$(ProjectDir)script" 
>   "$(ProjectDir)script\minified.js"

This was working fine when I kept all js files in the root of the script folder. But as it was starting to become alot of files in this folder, I decided to divide the files into subfolders. Now it seems that jsmin only fetches the js files in the root folder, and I cannot see that it has any option to include files in sub-folders. Does anyone have a good solution for a situation like this? Would seem to me that it should be a pretty common thing to do, so that is why I was a bit surprised it was not a parameter to jsmin.exe enabling sub-folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use DOS' `for` command to do that:

```
for /R "$(ProjectDir)scripts/debug" %s in (*.js) do JsMin.exe %s > "$(ProjectDir)scripts/release/%~ns.min.js"
```

That assumes the scripts are in (or in directories within) a directory named ~/scripts/debug and minifies them to ~/scripts/release with the .js replaced by .min.js.

I've tested that in CMD, but not as a build event in VS.  So, you may need to tweak the syntax slightly.

Comment: That might work, Dave! But as I understand it, you will be generating one minified file for each js file by this way of doing it? So I can do all this first, and then run a single jsmin on all the generated outputs afterwards in order to get only one file then?

Comment: You could run a `type "$(ProjectDir)scripts/release/*.min.js" > "$(ProjectDir)scripts/release/combined.js"` to combine them afterward.

Comment: Have tried this out now, and it seems to be working good, except the content of each *.min.js file is just "Parameters: [Source folder] [Target file] [r|x] [Match pattern]"

Excuse me for my lack in DOS skills, btw. As I understand it jsmin does not get the parameters it is looking for by this way of calling it. Do you understand why?

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems the JSmin version I'm using is a modified version taking other parameters than the standard. So I will just have to find the unmodified version and this should work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but below is the code to make Dave Ward's suggestion of recursively minifying javascript files.

Here is the code ported to work using a Visual Studio build event:

```
for /r "$(ProjectDir)scripts" %%s in (*.js) do $(SolutionDir)tools\jsmin.exe < %%s > "$(ProjectDir)debug\%%~ns.min.js"  

type "$(ProjectDir)debug\*.min.js" | "$(SolutionDir)tools\jsmin.exe" > "$(ProjectDir)release\local.min.js"

del "$(ProjectDir)debug\*.min.js"
```

The above code recurses the scripts folder (the root and sub-directories) for all scripts and places them in a debug folder (this can be any other folder in your directory as long as you have read/write perms set on it and it's not apart of the directory structure you are recursing. It then minifyies all the *.min.js  in the debug directory and cleans them up afterwards. I scoured the net trying to find this solution and couldn't so I hope this helps someone in need :)